# How to dry run with Trace Tables

Tags: algorithm, testing, trace

This is a **basic** question on the use of Trace Tables to assist in a dry run of a simple algorithm.

What I find most tricky is **when to take a new line in the trace table**?  For example, take the following question:

[image]

Here is the array of integers which it applies to:
[image]

The following trace table is presented as one completes a dry run.  Here is the solution:

[image]

I understand that initialising the variables *Number*, *Lower* & *Upper* appear on the first line, but when I go into the While Loop, I am tempted to put the value **5** **on the first line also**, for the variable *Current*.  In essence, this is what I am tempted to do:

[image]

Why does this solution  require that the value for Current, which is 5, appear on the second line? I suppose the question could be rephrased to '*When do I take a new line in a trace table?*'

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no specific way to do trace table, which means you have to setup your rules before you work and go on.
consider this example: 
[image]

and this also:
[image]

did you notice the difference between loop iterator in each one. In first example they put the initialization value of the iterator in first line, and in second example they put the initialization of the loop iterator in the second line.
also have a look at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_table) they also put the loop initialization in the second line.
also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dhIfUIoGQ4) has similar example to those I posted here and is always start loop iterator in the second line. 
also [this](http://www.101computing.net/trace-table/) example has totally different approach, which is each line of code in a new line in the trace table.
you can find also another different approach for trace table [here](https://retrosnob.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/trace-tables-chapter.pdf)

## Finally:

In my opinion chose the rules that make sense for you, for example: 
1-first line will contain the default values for the variables.
2-regarding loop iterations, put loop iterator in the same line as the variables that affected by this iteration, like the second example I posted above.
regarding your question I think it's more clear to put **Current** first value 5 in the second line, so you can track what each loop iteration affect your variables in a clear way.